# USB RFID reader + raspberry pi

Tags: python

i have usb RFID reader connected to raspberry pi 
the RFID reader is the Chinese brand it act like keyboard and it read the first 10 digit

so what i am trying to do here is read from the card and Compare with stored number in my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import sys

card = '0019171125'        # Stored good card number consider using a list or a file.
def main():                # define a main function.
while True:                # loop until the program encounters an error.
sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty0', 'r')
RFID_input = input()            
if RFID_input == card:      # coppare the stored number to the input and if True execute code.
  print "Access Granted" 
  print "Read code from RFID reader:{0}".format(RFID_input)
else:                    # and if the condition is false excecute this code.
  print "Access Denied"
  tty.close()
 main()                       # call the main function.
```

but this error keep showing

> RFID_input = input()
>                             ^
>   IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

any suggestion

Comment: You're not indenting your code correctly. All of the code under `main()` should be indented, and the `while` loop requires an indent as well.

Comment: I think you should really read a tutorial on python before continuing with your project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python is indentation-sensitive, so you need to indent your code properly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import sys

card = '0019171125'
def main():
    while True:
        sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty0', 'r')
        RFID_input = input()
        if RFID_input == card:
            print "Access Granted"
            print "Read code from RFID reader:{0}".format(RFID_input)
        else:
            print "Access Denied"
            tty.close()
main()
```

Note that `tty.close()` will raise an error because there is no `tty` defined. You probably want to close `sys.stdin` there, although it’s definitely not a good idea to use `sys.stdin` for a different stream when you could read from that stream directly instead.

Also, don’t use `input()` for user input, use `raw_input`.

---

```
def main():
    with open('/dev/tty0', 'r') as tty:
        while True:
            RFID_input = tty.readline()
            if RFID_input == card:
                print "Access Granted" 
                print "Read code from RFID reader:{0}".format(RFID_input)
            else:
                print "Access Denied"
```

Comment: it work but it give "Access Denied" every time Although the card number is correct

Comment: Your RFID reader most probably adds a newline character to the end of the ID read from the tag, so you'll have to strip that newline character before comparing with the allowed ID. You can do that using rstrip():

`RFID_input = tty.readline().rstrip()`

Answer (score 1):

With correct indentation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import sys

card = '0019171125'        # Stored good card number consider using a list or a file.

def main():                # define a main function.
    while True:            # loop until the program encounters an error.
        sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty0', 'r')
        RFID_input = input()            
        if RFID_input == card:      # compare the stored number to the input and if True execute code.
            print "Access Granted" 
            print "Read code from RFID reader:{0}".format(RFID_input)
        else:                    # and if the condition is false excecute this code.
            print "Access Denied"

# where is tty defined??
            tty.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But still you don't have tty defined...

Comment: I am new programing and this Chinese rfid reader work like keyboard but it does not in RPI except this way which i found in this link

[link](http://goo.gl/M7VMcY)


So what am trying to do is to surround it with if statement to verify the authorized card and do something 


Picture of rfid reader in this link 
[link](http://goo.gl/LxF2ay)

Comment: and i have no idea how to define tty